# conversion string to int with cast in C

Tags: c, string, casting, type-conversion

i have a string (five characters) and i tried to do an int cast to convert the entire string in a unique value. It worked but i want to know what appens during the conversion. For example

```
int main(){
char s[6];
int number;
Scanf("%s",s);
Number=(int)s;
Printf("%d",number);}
```

Thank you

Comment: Please update your question so the code is the same as what you actually compiled. Copy-and-paste it, don't re-type it. (Hint: `Int` and `int` are distinct in C.)

Comment: First: `char s[5];` does not have enough space for a 5-character string; you need to account for the `'\0'` terminator.

Comment: You **can** cast as you show (if compiled correctly) but you will be converting the *address* of the string to an `int`, not the value of the textual number in the string. There are various methods to do that, for example `sscanf()` and `atoi()`. Even better would be `scanf("%d", &number);`

Comment: I'm using this method to convert an user password from string to number. It isn"t the address because on different machines, the same string returns the same integer.

Comment: Your `Scanf()` and `Printf()` functions are non-standard (and `number` and `Number` are different variables).  Presumably, you mean `scanf()` and `printf()`, but C is a case-sensitive language and if you write the name with leading capitals, no-one can be sure about what you mean.  Also, the `}` on the end of a line is horrible, abominable style for C; completely non-recommended.  (It's also weird that you can get capitals on names when you don't need it, but can't get 'i' as 'I' when you do need it).

Comment: @MarcoDeSimone: Yes, it is the address. I don't know why you're getting the same integer on different machines; that could be coincidence, or the two machines could just be similar (addresses are typically relative to start of the current process, not the system's entire memory).

Comment: I see you've updated the code in your question. It's closer to being a complete program, but it still will not compile. Show us your *actual* code, not some approximation of it.

Comment: Changing a char in the string changes the value...

Comment: That seems unlikely. I can't be sure, since you *still* haven't shown us your actual code, but the address of the first element of an array will not change when you change the array's contents. You might get different results on different runs of the program.

Comment: Try this: http://pastebin.com/xkzsXb47 -- it should print the same number 4 times.

Comment: @RSahu: Please do not recommend that tutorial. It recommends using the `gets()` function, which is inherently unsafe and has been removed from the language.

Comment: Question: how does this work? Answer: it doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method you seem to be trying to use **does not work**.

`s` is an array expression. In most (but not all!) contexts, an array expression is implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element.

So you have:

```
char s[5];
int number;
number = (int)s;
```

`s`, after the implicit conversion, yields a pointer to the first element of the array, equivalent to `&s[0]`.  The cast converts that pointer value to type `int`, yielding a result that may or may not be at all meaningful (it can lose information if pointers happen to be wider than `int` on your system).

You say it "works", but it doesn't do at all what you intend. Two different arrays holding the same string value will have distinct addresses, and will *probably* yield distinct `int` values when converted.

If you want to track the distinct address of each array object, use pointers, not integers. If, for some reason, you need distinct integer values corresponding to addresses, use the type `intptr_t` or `uintptr_t`, defined in `<stdint.h>` to guarantee that you won't lose information (but it rarely makes sense to do that).

A cast (an explicit conversion) can be thought of as a way to tell the compiler that you know exactly what you're doing, and to override type checking (that's an oversimplification). If you *do* know what you're doing, that's fine. If you don't, you're likely to shoot yourself in the foot.

You're trying to get unique values corresponding to strings. What is your actual goal? Why can't you use the strings themselves as unique values?

Also, this:

```
scanf("%s",s);
```

is unsafe. It will read a whitespace-delimited sequence of characters of any arbitrary length from standard input. By defining `char s[5]`, you've only allowed enough room for a 4-character string (plus 1 for the terminating `'\0'`). If the user types more than that, the extra characters will clobber other memory, with unpredictable results (the technical term is *undefined behavior*).

Comment: The goal is to have a sort of hash of the string. I know that there are errors, but i' m trying to know how this works. Thank you

Comment: @MarcoDeSimone: I hope you understand that the method you're trying to use **doesn't** work.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand your question ignoring minor mistakes

```
number =(int)s;
```

in your case s is a pointer to an array of 5 characters,and it stores the address of the starting  memory address location of the array . So on casting it to integer it simply copies the pointer value which is an integer to the number variable.

So you will get different values of number(as memory allocated for s varies with each execution mostly) for the same string entered in the console.

Comment: Does this add any information that wasn't already in my answer?

Comment: after posting my answer i could see there was another answer.I will delete if its a duplicate..

Answer (score 0):

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<stdlib.h>

 void main()
 {
   char arr[10] ="9821" ;// string in c 
   int a = 0 ;           // variable with data type int initialize by 0   

   a = atoi(arr);        // function of stdlib.h file convert arry to int and asign value to a 
   printf("%i",a) ;      // print int data form integer variable a

 }
```